# JavascriptObservable Storage

Tags: javascript

I created this observable storage thing in JavaScript (partly for fun, but also because it came in handy and got bigger without me noticing it).

The repository can be found [here](https://github.com/pinoniq/eagle).

```
(function(window, undefined){
    "use strict";

    var eagle = window.eagle = (function() {

        var storage = {
            feathers : {},
            observers : {}
        }

        function storeFeather(name, data) {
            var action;
            if ( (name in storage.feathers) ) {
                action = 'update';
            } else {
                action = 'insert';
            }
            //for now, copletly overwrite the shit out of it
            storage.feathers[name] = data;

            notifyObservers(name, action);
        }

        function retrieveFeather(name) {
            return storage.feathers[name];
        }

        function destroyFeather(name) {
            delete storage.feathers[name];
            notifyObservers(name, 'destroy');
        }

        function notifyObservers(observerTarget, action) {
            if ( !(observerTarget in storage.observers) ) {
                return;
            }

            if ( !(action in storage.observers[observerTarget]) ) {
                return;
            }

            var observers = storage.observers[observerTarget][action];

            for ( var i=0, len=observers.length; i<len; i++ ) {
                observers[i](storage.feathers[observerTarget], action);
            }
        }

        function registerObserver(observerTarget, action, task) {
            if ( !(observerTarget in storage.observers) ) {
                storage.observers[observerTarget] = [];
            }

            if ( action instanceof Array ) {
                for ( var i=0, len=action.length; i<len; i++ ) {
                    registerObserverForAction(observerTarget, action[i], task);
                }
            } else if ( typeof action == 'string' ) {
                registerObserverForAction(observerTarget, action, task);
            }
        }

        function registerObserverForAction(observerTarget, action, task) {
            if ( !(action in storage.observers[observerTarget]) ) {
                storage.observers[observerTarget][action] = [];
            }

            storage.observers[observerTarget][action].push(task);
        }

        return {
            observe : function() {
                switch( arguments.length ) {
                    case 2:
                        return registerObserver(
                            arguments[0],
                            ['update','insert','destroy'],
                            arguments[1]
                        );
                    break;

                    case 3:
                        return registerObserver(
                            arguments[0],
                            arguments[1],
                            arguments[2]
                        );
                    break;

                    default:
                        throw "Invalid arguments length";
                    break;
                }
            },

            store : function() {
                switch( arguments.length ) {
                    case 2:
                        return storeFeather(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
                    break;

                    default:
                        throw "Invalid arguemnts length";
                    break;
                }
            },

            retrieve : function() {
                switch( arguments.length ) {
                    case 1:
                        return retrieveFeather(arguments[0]);
                    break;

                    default:
                        throw "Invalid arguemnts length";
                    break;
                }
            },

            destroy : function() {
                switch( arguments.length ) {
                    case 1:
                        return destroyFeather(arguments[0]);
                    break;

                    default:
                        throw "Invalid arguemnts length";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    })();
})(this);
```

### Usage:

#### Store

Store the data in the eagle. Data is stored as a so called Feather.

```
eagle.store('my-data', {
    actual : 'data'
});
```

#### Retrieve

Retrieve stored data from the eagle.

```
eagle.retrieve('my-data'); // {actual:'data'}
```

#### Destroy

completly remove data from the eagle. Uses delete internally.

```
eagle.destroy('my-data');
```

#### Observer

If we need to keep track of what is happening to our data stored inside the eagle. We can add observers.
Observers are notified when something happens to the Feather.

```
eagle.observe('my-data', function(feather, action) {
    console.log('something happened to my-model');
    console.log('That something is '+action);
    console.log('The data now is: '+feather);
});
```

If you would like to observe only a certain action. This can be done bypassing an extra parameter:

```
eagle.observe('my-data', 'update', function(feather, action) {
    console.log('something happened to my-model');
    console.log('That something is '+action);
    console.log('The data now is: '+feather);
});
```

Comment: @Jamal I don't think your edit was correct. Some fun should be allowed!

Comment: Just my 2 cents: look into `Object.defineProperty` to set methods/properties that should not be editable by the user...

Comment: Problem was that IE8 only allows that on DOM elements. And I am lucky enough to have to support IE8 on the project I am using it in :p

Comment: @Pinoniq: That was mostly noise (especially as a question), and a post should be free from it.  If you'd like to do this in the proper place, you may join us in chat.

Comment: [Follow-up question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64977/javascript-observable-storage-revised)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few comments:

- You probably want to use `foo.hasOwnProperty(bar)` instead of `bar in foo`. What happens if someone adds feather called "constructor?"
- Using `window` for the global object feels wrong. What if someone runs this in a non-browser environment?
- The `undefined` parameter is never used.
- You've got your code nested in two IIFEs where one would do.
- Throw errors, not strings. Or better yet, don't throw anything, because...
- Checking for "invalid argument lengths" adds bloat and probably is not necessary. If you document your functions properly and people try to call them with an invalid argument list, that's user error. User error is not something your program should have to worry about* (but good documentation is).
- `observerTarget` can probably just be `target`. I think `observers[target]` is a bit easier to mentally parse than `observers[observerTarget]`; the latter feels redundant and makes me wonder what other kind of target there might be.
- I see no reason to have `feathers` and `observers` as properties of another object; these can just be variables.

These are mostly nitpicks, all in all the code looks good. For what it's worth, here's how I might have written it:

```
(function (global) {
    'use strict';

    var feathers = {},
        observers = {};

    function storeFeather(name, data) {
        var action = feathers.hasOwnProperty(name) ? 'update' : 'insert';

        feathers[name] = data;
        notifyObservers(name, action);
    }

    function retrieveFeather(name) {
        return feathers[name];
    }

    function destroyFeather(name) {
        delete feathers[name];
        notifyObservers(name, 'destroy');
    }

    function notifyObservers(target, action) {
        if (!observers.hasOwnProperty(target)) {
            return;
        }

        if (!observers[target].hasOwnProperty(action)) {
            return;
        }

        var reactors = observers[target][action];

        for (var i = 0, len = reactors.length; i < len; i++) {
            reactors[i](feathers[target], action);
        }
    }

    function registerObserverForAction(target, action, task) {
        if (!observers[target].hasOwnProperty(action)) {
            observers[target][action] = [];
        }

        observers[target][action].push(task);
    }

    function registerObserver(target, action, task) {
        if (!observers.hasOwnProperty(target)) {
            observers[target] = [];
        }

        if (arguments.length < 3) {
            task = action;
            action = ['update', 'insert', 'destroy'];
        }

        if (action instanceof Array) {
            for (var i = 0, len = action.length; i < len; i++) {
                registerObserverForAction(target, action[i], task);
            }
        } else if (typeof action == 'string') {
            registerObserverForAction(target, action, task);
        }
    }

    var eagle = {
        observe: registerObserver,
        store: storeFeather,
        retrieve: retrieveFeather,
        destroy: destroyFeather
    };

    global.eagle = eagle;

})(this);
```

<sup>* The user in question being another programmer, of course. End-user error is always something to worry about.</sup>

Comment: +1. Particularly for `User [i.e. programmer] error is not something your program should have to worry about* (but good documentation is)`

Comment: some good comments. About the window object. I use the first IIFE to pass in the window object ((this) at the bottom). So the window inside my first IIFE is whatever enviroment this code is being executed in. The rest of the comments, really liked them

Comment: @Pinoniq, about the window thing, I know, I just prefer to name the local variable something like "global," it seems more fitting than "window" (because it might not always be a window).

Answer (score 4):

Pretty nice! I have only a few comments:

1. You have a typo: "arguemnts" in your `throw` statements :)
2. I'd avoid all the extra logic in the returned object. I'd prefer the functions to be doing all the argument handling themselves. I do understand why you'd split up the logic, but at the same time you're, well, splitting up the logic.
3. There should probably be a way to remove observers...
4. You could consider more conventional naming, like `on` or `addEventListener` for observers. You say "observer", but I'd rather say "event handler", since it's not total value observing.
   If I do:

   ```
   var data = { foo: "bar" };
   eagle.observe("data", dataChanged);
   eagle.store("data", data); // will call dataChanged
   data.foo = "baz";          // will *not* call dataChanged
   ```

   It's a minor thing, and as much a question of personal preference, but I find the word "observe" to imply more than what's actually happening here.

Comment: Yeah, dataChanged will indeed only becalled when 'saving' data via store. This is how I wanted it to be :p It was by design ;) But it might be a cool thing to have a save() function or so. I might encapsulate the data in a Feather function or so with a save() method. will see :)