# Observable storage - revised

Tags: javascript, database, callback

Previous question:

[JavascriptObservable Storage](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58515/javascriptobservable-storage)

The idea is to have some storage interface that exists of different *buckets* - known as `Eagle`s:

```
Eagle('bucket1');
Eagle('bucket2');
```

Every `Eagle` data is stored as `Feather`s.

```
var e = Eagle('fooEagle');
e.set('myFeather',{
    'foo' : 'bar';
});
```

These `Feather`s can be observed for changes (nothing more at this moment):

```
var f = e.get('myFeather');
f.on('change',function(f, key) {
    console.log(key+ ' index of the Feather was changed to'+ f.get(key)));
});
f.set('foo','newer foo');
```

You could also retrieve data in a long chain like this:

```
Eagle('fooEagle').get('myFeather').get('foo');
```

Does this seem like a good approach? If so, how would you implement events like 'delete'. And would it be useful to let those events bubble up to the `Eagle`? If so, how?

```
window.Eagle = (function(){
    "use strict";

    var _eagleInstances = [],
        _featherInstances = [];

    var Feather = (function() {
        var _data = {},
            _observers = {};

        var F = function(data) {
            this._id = _featherInstances.length;
            _featherInstances[this._id] = this;
            _data[this._id] = data;
        }

        F.prototype.has = function(key) {
            return _data[this._id].hasOwnProperty(key);
        }

        F.prototype.get = function(key) {
            return this.has(key) ? _data[this._id][key] : undefined;
        }

        F.prototype.set = function(key, data) {
            _data[this._id][key] = data;
            this.notify('change', key);
            return this;
        }

        F.prototype.on = function(action, callable) {
            if ( ! _observers.hasOwnProperty(action) ) {
                _observers[action] = [];
            }

            _observers[action].push(callable);
        }

        F.prototype.notify = function(action, info) {
            if ( _observers.hasOwnProperty(action) ) {
                for ( var i = 0; i < _observers[action].length; i++ ) {
                    _observers[action][i](this, info);
                }
            }
        }

        return F;
    })();

    var Eagle = (function(){
        var _feathers = {};

        var E = function() {
            this._id = _eagleInstances.length;
            _feathers[this._id] = {};
            _eagleInstances[this._id] = this;
        }

        E.prototype.has = function(featherIdentifier) {
            return _feathers[this._id].hasOwnProperty(featherIdentifier);
        }

        E.prototype.get = function(featherIdentifier) {
            if ( !this.has(featherIdentifier) ) {
                this.set(featherIdentifier, {});
            }
            return _featherInstances[_feathers[this._id][featherIdentifier]];
        }

        E.prototype.set = function(featherIdentifier, data) {
            var f = new Feather(data);
            _feathers[this._id][featherIdentifier] = f._id;
            return f;
        }

        return E;
    })();

    return function(eagleIdentifier) {
        if ( !_eagleInstances.hasOwnProperty(eagleIdentifier) ) {
            _eagleInstances[eagleIdentifier] = new Eagle();
        }
        return _eagleInstances[eagleIdentifier];
    }

})();
```

Comment: A good primer on how Collections (Eagles) and Models (Feathers) work would be Backbone. Check it out and model your stuff around it.

Answer (score 1):

I am just going to comment on a few things because I don't think I have a great high level understanding of your code is meant to do (not that is bad for any reason).

In general I would avoid adding scope to variables if it is not needed, for example instead of declaring `_data` that is available to the whole `F` class and reference it with a special id I would just put a new data object on each instance.  Keep in mind limiting the scope of variables would apply for `_featherInstances` and `_eagleInstances` as well but there could be some business reason for it that I don't understand.

```
     var F = function(data) {
                this._id = _featherInstances.length;
                _featherInstances[this._id] = this;
                this._data = data;
            }

        F.prototype.has = function(key) {
            return this._data.hasOwnProperty(key);
        }
   ...
```

Another note to make is has might not work as you expected it.  For example:

`new F({key: undefined}).has('key')` would return true

Comment: The reason I scope the _data var is to make it unaccessible from the outside. otherwise one could access the data using F._data

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that, `_data` indicates that it is private and no matter what it is named if it is not documented it is not part of your public api.  I generally avoid code overhead and closures to prevent someone from possibly doing something wrong.